# Running Observables Sequentially while passing Parameters in RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I was trying to perform a task using RxJava. Basically, there are four observables. I figured out how to run Observables sequentially. However, I could not get the answer to how I can pass one output to the other. The Observables are like,

1. Get Remote Data such as List
2. Get Local Data same List
3. Delete All Local data from 2nd Observable
4. Insert Remote List

I am using retrofit and Room to access remote and local data respectively. Any help or suggestion would be really great.

So far, what I did is (this is not right for sure)

```
disposables.add(Observable.zip(dataManager.allXs, dataManager.Xs, object : BiFunction<List<X>, List<X>, List<X>> {
        @Throws(Exception::class)
        override fun apply( s: List<X>, s2: List<X>): List<X> {
            dataManager.deleteXs(s2)
            return s
        }
    }).map {
        dataManager.insertXs(it)
    }. subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
        subscribe { 

        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe first 2 observables can be zipped

Comment: Try using `combineLatest` (http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html). This way, it will wait for first and second observable to fetch data, and then you will have both of them in one function. You can then delete local and insert remote list.